# Is Azure Outbound Bandwidth free for first 5 GB every month?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I am confused about Azure Bandwidth outbound data-transfer pricing. The [official](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/bandwidth/) website says that the First 5 GB/Month is free.

Suppose I have used 5 GB in January, then in February will it get reset and restart counting of 5 GB again? Are first 5 GB free in every month? Are these bandwidths free irrespective of resource i.e Virtual machines, App Services etc?

Comment: I'm guessing it's per billing period and irrespective of what the resource is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the first 5 GB of Outbound Data Transfer is *free each month*. This means any and all* outbound traffic from your Azure Resources.

So either when you're downloading data from Azure Storage, have a (data intensive) app running in a VM sending out a lot of data or download Azure SQL Database backups every night: you're consuming outbound data.

Please be advised that data going out of the Azure Region is counted as outbound traffic. So **data that you copy between Azure Regions is counted as outbound data**.

*As you can see in the article you shared:

> Bandwidth refers to data moving in and out of Azure data centers other than those explicitly covered by the Content Delivery Network or ExpressRoute pricing.